# X-HTTP-Method-Override in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, http-headers, put

How can I do an X-HTTP-Method-Override for an ajax request in jQuery?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With 1.5 you can now pass in a headers option:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: {
    'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'DELETE'
  },
  method: 'GET'
  // more parameters...
});
```

This is set before 'beforeSend' is called, so it could still get overwritten. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

-- fixed incorrect syntax (wouldn't let me save with less than 6 character edit, so writing this message

Answer (score 26):

You could set custom headers when performing an ajax request by using the [beforeSend](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) callback:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'PUT');
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/someurl',
    success: function(data){
        // do something...
    }
});
```