# How to detect if browser supports PUT/DELETE verbs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatic way to see if client browser supports PUT / DELETE methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627998/programmatic-way-to-see-if-client-browser-supports-put-delete-methods)

What is the best way to determine if a browser supports PUT/DELETE verbs?

I'd prefer Feature Detection, over Browser Detection.